# Finding out scroll direction in react-native listview/scrollview

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-scrollview

Is there a way to find out the scroll direction of react-native's listview/scrollview components?

Native iOS components seem to be able to do it by calculating the offset from `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and `scrollViewDidScroll`, but there seems to be no bindings for these.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use the onScroll event of a ScrollView and check the contentOffset in the event callback:

https://rnplay.org/apps/FltwOg

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  offset: 0,
  onScroll: function(event) {
    var currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        var direction = currentOffset > this.offset ? 'down' : 'up';
    this.offset = currentOffset;
    console.log(direction);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroller} onScroll={this.onScroll}>
          <Text>Scrollable content here</Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  scroller: {
    height: 5000,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Yup, just realized onScroll returns synthetic events :) Can you add the code here (in case rnplay goes down?) I'll accept it once so

Comment: If you are using ES6 classes, you will have to make sure your onScroll callback is bound to the component instance.

Comment: This used to work, but sometimes in iOS, the scroll direction changes when scroll ends the movement, to oposite direction.

Comment: There are some bug if you change the header visible above the scrollview,some time the direction gotten is opposite.Especially on android.

Comment: How to get above functionality with hooks because with hooks how can we get this.offset  .

Answer (score 21):

I had problems with alexp's solution to accurately specify the direction when the difference between the old and the new offset was very small. So I filtered them out.

```
  _onScroll = event => {
    const currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const dif = currentOffset - (this.offset || 0);

    if (Math.abs(dif) < 3) {
      console.log('unclear');
    } else if (dif < 0) {
      console.log('up');
    } else {
      console.log('down');
    }

    this.offset = currentOffset;
  };
```

Comment: So Helpful and Simple!